# Can Counting Sort have a runtime that is not O(k+n)?

Tags: algorithms

I'm reading CLRS right now and it gives an overall time of O(k + n) and when k = O(n), the running time is O(n).

So my question is, what would make the sort run in something other than O(n)?

Comment: Mh, what is the size of the storage ?

Comment: In fact, the running time can be $O(k)$ in some circumstances.

Comment: Why would that be? And thank you Yves. Can you say why you asked about size of storage?

Comment: To let you think about the problem and better understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose your inputs are in the range $0$ to $n^2$. How long does it take to walk through the array of counts?

Comment: Wouldn't it still be O(n)?

Comment: No; that's why I wrote the question.

Comment: Then what would it be.

Comment: And *that* is why I asked it as a question rather than simply writing the answer: I was hoping you'd think hard about it for a little while. So, apparently, was @YvesDaoust, when he wrote his comment. But I'll make that a little clearer by adding the word "Hint:", so that it's clear it's not intended to be a complete answer.

Comment: How bout just post the runtime? I'm not trying to dive too deep on this one. Thanks.

Comment: You already know the answer; it's in your question. The runtime is $O(k+n)$.